# Get the title of custom post type in another loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am in the single-product.php loop and the product has a relationship to an artist post type to which I have the id off the artist.

I need to get the_title() from my custom artist post type while in the single-product.php loop.

My code is getting the title of the product rather than the artist. My code is below. Can anyone please help?

```
    $artistId = get_field('artist');

    $postId = get_post($artistId);
    if ( $postId ):
        setup_postdata($postId);
        ?>
        <span id="chty_17">
            <dt><?php the_title(); ?></dt>
        </span>
        <?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a post ID to `get_the_title()`.  So instead of using `the_title()` to display it, fetch it first like this.

```
$artist_title = get_the_title( $artistID );
echo $artist_title;
```

You could do that in one line of course but you might need it somewhere else, too.

Comment: Great thank you! Will make sure I remember that in future!

Comment: Happy to help and glad it worked for you.